# Update multiple values using IS NULL condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I just finished migrating an Access database to the SQL Server and I need to fix the Yes/No values to be defaulted to No as their data type conversion is set to **bit**.

I do this by setting the default value to 0.

However, I want to execute a query to do that as well, but there are multiple bit rows.

I know how to use multiples with the SET command, but how do we use multiple with WHERE? What is the proper way of structuring it?

```
UPDATE sometable SET
    [isConditionOnePassed] = 0
    , [isSecondPassed] = 0
    , [isThirdPassed] = 0
WHERE [isConditionOnePassed] IS NULL, [isSecondPassed] is NULL, [isThirdPassed] IS NULL
```

Or is it with an AND? Like boolean logic?

```
UPDATE sometable SET
    [isConditionOnePassed] = 0
    , [isSecondPassed] = 0
    , [isThirdPassed] = 0
WHERE [isConditionOnePassed] IS NULL and [isSecondPassed] is NULL and [isThirdPassed] IS NULL
```

Comment: Went straight back to fixing my queries. Answer is accepted now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If you want to set `NULL` values to another value, you can use `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE sometable
    SET isConditionOnePassed = COALESCE(isConditionOnePassed, 0),
        isSecondPassed = COALESCE(isSecondPassed, 0), 
        isThirdPassed = COALESDCE(isThirdPassed, 0)
   WHERE isConditionOnePassed IS NULL OR isSecondPassed is NULL OR isThirdPassed IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what you *really* need is an `ISNULL` or `CASE` expression. Here is an example with both:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.SomeTable
SET isConditionOnePassed = ISNULL(isConditionOnePassed,0),
    isSecondPassed = CASE isSecondPassed WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```